# Taxonomy term option is missing in view category

Tags: views, 8

I have several site on Drupal 8.5  where I don’t see the "taxonomy term" option in view. So I can’t create a view that lists taxonomy terms of a vocabulary.

See the first screen shot to see the problem.

[image]

Why I don’t see this option ? Is there something to install or enable ? I’ve checked a lot of things and I still don’t understand.

Below, there is a second screen shot of an other Drupal where I have this really useful field.

[image]

Finally, this is what I would like to add in `fields` and `Filter` in view.

[image]

Comment: But you have all relevant taxonomy modules enabled, do you?

Comment: @leymannx I have taxonomy module enabled on both websites. Is there an other module I need ?

Comment: No that should be just fine. Do you also have all relevant taxonomy permissions granted?

Comment: @leymannx Permissions seems to be correctly configured. I’ve installed a clean Drupal with `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev drupal --stability dev --no-interaction`and I see the same thing. The option in the select list are not the same as before (`category : global or taxonomy term`). Now I have `Comment statistics, Content, Content Revision, File Usage, Global, Search`.

Comment: So, when you go to `/admin/structure/views/add` you can't select `Taxonomy terms` under `VIEW SETTINGS`?

Comment: And in your existing content view under `ADVANCED` and `RELATIONSHIPS` you can't select `Taxonomy terms on node`, too?

Comment: @leymannx Yes, thank you, you’re right, it was simply that I didn’t choose the correct option when i created the view (`/admin/structure/views/add`). I feel a little awkward to have asked this. Please post it as an answer and i I’ll vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to choose "Taxonomy terms" under `VIEW SETTINGS` when you add a new view on `MYSITE/admin/structure/views/add`.

[image]

Comment: Just curious if your master view setting is "content", is it possible to add a, say block display, that uses taxonomy term as the content to show?